# i have a coding problem with a loop task, more info below

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, javahelp

I have a task to create a program using only for loop and math functions that input N amount of cars and each iteration gets the time it took the car to reach the end, the final output needs to be the first one to reach the end and the second, meaning the two lowest times.

I've created a program:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.println("enter total cars: ");
    int cars = sc.nextInt();
    double first = 0, second = 0;
    int car1 = 1, car2 = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= cars; i++) {
        System.out.println("enter car number " + i + " speed:");
        double speed = sc.nextDouble();
        if (i == 1) {
            first = speed;
            second = speed;
        }   
        
        if (speed < first) {
            second = first;
            first = speed;
            car2 = car1;
            car1 = i;
        } else {
            
            if (speed < second) {
                car2 = i;
                second = speed; 
            }
            
    
        }
    

    }
    System.out.println("car number one is " + car1 +" with speed of " + first);
    System.out.println("car number two is " + car2 +" with speed of " + second);
}
```

}

the problem I had is how to start the first and second var, as they cant be set to 0, because I need to check if the speed I get is lower than the first or the second. i tried maybe on the first iteration to set first and second to speed to have something to start with, but it still bugs, so I wondered how could I fix it?
thanks ahead.

Comment: What is the purpose of entering total number of cars if all of your code is just for 2 cars anyway?  I am not really following

Comment: Oh, theres not only two cars, the amount of cars is N, n total amount. its an input.
what I need to do is for example if the input is 5 there's 5 cars.
and I everytime give the time for each for for example
car 1 - 10
car 2 - 30
car 3 - 5.3
car 4 = 20
car 5 = 12
the output needs to be
first car to reach the end car 3 with time of 5.3
second car to reach the end car 1 with time of 10

Comment: But then why is the `System.out.print` statements specifically saying "car number one" and "car number two", where is "car number three" if I entered 3?  Sounds like you just need to use an array

Comment: it asks everytime for the car speed, so it will be organized, so the guy who uses the program will know what car he's currently giving the speed of I know an array works better but its a task and I'm only allowed to use for loops and math functions also if statement of course to make this

Comment: if the input is 5 there's 5 cars. and I everytime give the time for each for for example car 1 - 10 car 2 - 30 car 3 - 5.3 car 4 = 20 car 5 = 12 the output needs to be first car to reach the end car 3 with time of 5.3 second car to reach the end car 1 with time of 10

Comment: So you only need to know the first two cars to reach the end and not any others?

Comment: i need not the two first cars, but the two cars whose time to *reach the end is the lowest*

Comment: oh sorry, thats kinda what you said, yes

Comment: i also need their number, so like if car number 6 took 3 second and all the other others were bigger the first car time to reach the end was 3 and the car number is 6

Comment: I posted an answer using the info you gave in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code below that will let the user enter any number of cars, ask for their time taken, and then print the car number of the two lowest times and their respective time taken:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter total cars: ");
    int totalCars = sc.nextInt();
    
    double firstPlaceTime = Double.MAX_VALUE, secondPlaceTime = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    int firstPlaceNumber = 0, secondPlaceNumber = 0;
    
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalCars; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter car number " + i + " time:");
        double currentTime = sc.nextDouble();
        
        if (currentTime < firstPlaceTime) {
            secondPlaceTime = firstPlaceTime;
            secondPlaceNumber = firstPlaceNumber;
            firstPlaceTime = currentTime;
            firstPlaceNumber = i;
        }
        else if (currentTime < secondPlaceTime) {
            secondPlaceTime = currentTime;
            secondPlaceNumber = i;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("car number one is " + firstPlaceNumber +" with time of " + firstPlaceTime);
    System.out.println("car number two is " + secondPlaceNumber +" with time of " + secondPlaceTime);
}
```

The important part is that you can initialize the time `double` values using `Double.MAX_VALUE` in order to ensure the first 2 cars will always replace the initial values:

```
double firstPlaceTime = Double.MAX_VALUE, secondPlaceTime = Double.MAX_VALUE;
```

Besides that the code honestly has the confusing variable names.  I used longer names that have more meaning in order to make the code easier to understand.

**Example Run:**

```
enter total cars: 
4
Enter car number 1 time:
50
Enter car number 2 time:
30
Enter car number 3 time:
40
Enter car number 4 time:
60
car number one is 2 with time of 30.0
car number two is 3 with time of 40.0
```

Comment: The thing is, your program says the two it took the longest, but I need the one that it took the lowest to, so if I give 4 cars

car 1 - 50
car 2 - 30
car 3 - 40
car 4 - 60
with your program it will print car 4 with 60 and car 1 with 50,

Comment: The car with the highest speed would take the shortest time?  It says speed not time, unless whatever you are talking about is not speed at all

Comment: but it needs to print
car 2 with 30
car 3 with 40

the lowest one who reached the end

Comment: And like if i change the sign for < to > it doesn't work, because it always checks if the number is lower than 0 and it cant. so that where the problem starts

Comment: Okay, so "speed" is not speed it is time, as in seconds it took them?

Comment: I named the vars worng, its like the car with the lowest time to reach the end, like a race with two winners

Comment: I see, I will fix the answer in a bit

Comment: Yeah as in seconds it took them

Comment: @fun Try it now

Comment: I think it will work, but the thing is if I can't use max value or positive infinity, what other alternatives do I have?

Comment: Well a `Map` would be the easiest way, but you probably can't use that either?  You could always just separate the code for the first 2 cars from the loop and use them to initialize two cars manually and then have the loop start at `i = 3` or the 3rd car.

Comment: yeah, alright
Thank you so much! Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

So it will be something like this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter total cars: ");
    int totalCars = sc.nextInt();
    
    double temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0, firstPlaceTime = 0, secondPlaceTime = 0;
    int firstPlaceNumber = 0, secondPlaceNumber = 0;
    
   System.out.println("Enter car number 1 time:");
     temp1 = sc.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter car number 2 time:");
    temp2 = sc.nextDouble();
    
    firstPlaceTime = Math.max(temp1, temp2);
    secondPlaceTime = Math.min(temp1, temp2);

    
    for (int i = 3; i <= totalCars; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter car number " + i + " time:");
         double currentTime = sc.nextDouble();
        
        if (currentTime < firstPlaceTime) {
            secondPlaceTime = firstPlaceTime;
            secondPlaceNumber = firstPlaceNumber;
            firstPlaceTime = currentTime;
            firstPlaceNumber = i;
        }
        else if (currentTime < secondPlaceTime) {
            secondPlaceTime = currentTime;
            secondPlaceNumber = i;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("car number one is " + firstPlaceNumber +" with time of " + firstPlaceTime);
    System.out.println("car number two is " + secondPlaceNumber +" with time of " + secondPlaceTime);
}
```

}